# Creating a swatch of entire color spectrum

Tags: php, loops, colors, rgb

I'm trying to create a swatch every color, which I'll later have to match to the pixels of an image to create a mosaic.

As of now, it doesn't display anything. I'm not sure if I'm running the loop correctly. It's taking every number for $r$g$b then incrementing it and changing it to a hex format to be read and displayed.

Code is here:

```
$r = 000;
$g = 000;
$b = 000;

for($r = 000; $r <= 155; $r++) {
    for($r = 000; $r <= 155; $r++) {
        for($r = 000; $r <= 155; $r++) {

        echo '<span style="width: 5px; height: 5px; background-color-color:#'.dechex($r).dechex($g).dechex($b).'">.</span>';


        }

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you're using $r on the three loops, and it should be one for each variable. and they should run to 255 instead of 155.
not really tied to your question, but if you declare a number with leading 0 , it is in octal

Comment: be wary that dechex doesn't include the leading 0 for values 0 to F, so your css will be wrong. use background-color:rgb($r,$g,$b) rather than converting to hex

Comment: @Einacio: True, true, true. +1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues here:

- I see three loops which are all setting `$r`, which should probably be `$r`, `$g`, and `$b`.
- You probably want to increase each of the variables by more than 1 at each step. As written (once the r/g/b fix is done), the script you've got will generate about 273 MB of HTML output, which will yield a page about 100 feet tall (on screen, assuming 72 dpi).
- The maximum value for a color is 255, not 155 (unless you don't like bright colors).
- The CSS selector you're looking for is simply `background-color`, not `background-color-color`.
- You need to pad the hex colors with zeroes when they're under 16 (`10` hex). Easiest way to do this is:

  ```
  $color = sprintf("#%02x%02x%02x", $r, $g, $b);
  echo "... background-color:$color ...";
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($r = 0; $r <= 255; $r++)
{
    for ($g = 0; $g <= 255; $g++)
    {
        for ($b = 0; $b <= 255; $b++)
        {
            echo sprintf('<span style="width: 5px; height: 5px; background-color: #%02X%02X%02X">.</span>', $r, $g, $b);
        }
    }
}
```

You were only using `$r` in the loops, it's also 255 and not 155.

Bare in mind that this will create 256 * 256 * 256 = 16777216 `span` tags / swatches, besides making your browser eat a lof of memory it will also take a *while* to finish.

Answer (score 0):

So, this will be horrendously inefficient due to all the looping (creating 16 million spans), but your logic is correct(ish) so I'll answer the question.

```
for($r = 000; $r <= 155; $r++) {
    for($r = 000; $r <= 155; $r++) {
        for($r = 000; $r <= 155; $r++) {
```

A couple of flaws here:

- These all reference the $r variable
- They go up to 155, you probably meant 255?
- They start at 000, might as well just make that 0 as they equate to the same thing.

As for the next block:

```
echo '<span style="width: 5px; height: 5px; background-color-color:#'.dechex($r).dechex($g).dechex($b).'">.</span>';
```

The main flaw here is that you are doing background-color-color instead of background-color.

Answer (score 0):

There were multiple errors in your script, especially when formatting the color value. I opted for `sprintf` here as it does the job and is useful in other places as well. Then the CSS rule was wrong (`-color-color`). Additionally I've moved some of the styles into the head section to reduce the HTML output written. Additionally I've introduced a steps variable to not crash your browser ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KMeeO1)):

```
<head><style>div {width:5px; height:5px; float:left;}</style></head>
<?php

$min = 0;
$max = 256;
$step = 15;

for ($r = $min; $r < $max; $r+=$step)
{
    for ($g = $min; $g < $max; $g+=$step)
    {
        for ($b = $min; $b < $max; $b+=$step)
        {
            echo '<div style="background-color:', sprintf('#%02x%02x%02x', $r, $g, $b), '"></div>';
        }
    }
}
```

(Just seeing others have found the same issues in the meanwhile I was crashing my browser (and nicely explained), I leave the answer because of the demo.)